# Add value to a list inside a loop before an append

Tags: python, pandas

I am downloading multiple .csv from a website with the below code

```
states = ['ak', 'al']
path = 'https://data.openstates.org/people/current/'
data = []

for s in states:
    data.append(pd.read_csv(path + s + '.csv'))
```

I would like to add the a new value to the list state name from states to the downloaded list before the append.

Also I next build a dataframe from the list. If I use the code below I get the the data for AK.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data[0], columns = ['id', 'name', 'current_party', 'current_district', 'current_chamber', 'given_name', 'family_name', 'gender', 'email', 'biography', 'birth_date', 'death_date', 'image', 'links', 'sources', 'capitol_address', 'capitol_voice', 'capitol_fax', 'district_address', 'district_voice', 'district_fax', 'twitter', 'youtube', 'instagram', 'facebook'])
```

Is there a way for me to loop over data and get a dataframe with all states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
states = ['ak', 'al']
path = 'https://data.openstates.org/people/current/'
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(path + s + '.csv').assign(state=s) for s in states])
```

(Note your loop is doing `for states in states` which is probably a typo)